# How to install olaptrain sample schema on oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-12c

I need to install the sample schema available from the Oracle website:

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/warehouse/olap/olaptrain_install.zip

I am trying to run the commands as given here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/readme-098894.html

But I get this error:

```
ORA-01537: cannot add file 'dm.dbf' - file already part of database
```

---

Given below is the copy of the screen:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = pdborcl;

Session altered.

SQL> @install_olaptrain.sql

Specify file system directory containing this installation program.

Directory: C:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\olaptrain_install

Specify a password for the OLAPTRAIN user.
Password:

Begin installation
... creating tablespaces
  declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01537: cannot add file 'dm.dbf' - file already part of database
ORA-06512: at line 31
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved after changing the location for datafile in 'install_olaptrain.sql', and

changing the 'ho impdp' statement to the given below string resolves any login error in Oracle 12c:

ho impdp olaptrain/manager@//localhost:1521/my_pdb dumpfile=OLAPTRAIN12232009.DMP directory=OLAPTRAIN_INSTALL

But then "ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536" occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I've create the olaptrain user using the script in `install_olaptrain.sql` with tablespace default users.

Then imported with this string :

```
impdpd dwhadmin/********@svildwh directory=expdp_dir \
  dumpfile=OLAPTRAIN12232009.DMP logfile=test.log \
  schemas=olaptrain remap_tablespace=DM:USERS \ 
  remap_tablespace=DM_ARCHIVE:USERS
```

Import in pluggable database 12c.

All ok.